# Trying to install grpc-node locally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, grpc, node-pre-gyp

I'm trying to install grpc locally via `npm install`, and  command I used was `sudo npm i grpc --unsafe-perm`. I get an error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm on linux, ubuntu 18.04.1. I have node v11 and npm v6.4.1.

Here is the error log:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd /media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v11.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin- 
app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "-- 
fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /media/binyamin/Seagate Expansion   
Drive/Documents/GitHub/admin-app/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: It's possible that this is because I'm using node v11, which as of now has't even been out for a week.

Comment: It looks like you omitted a lot of the error log, but I would guess that you are encountering a known issue with installing on Node 11: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/594.